# Base-64 Encoding of SHA256 in Power Automate

Tags: base64, power-automate, sha256, xxd

We are trying to implement a hashing algorithm that takes the string `35FEBEA52A07816B0949505E46E6C8CB2B9D3896A625286BFA4CB04202452157` and produces the output `Nf6+pSoHgWsJSVBeRubIyyudOJamJShr+kywQgJFIVc=`. The documentation states this is the Base-64 encoding of the string, however, using the `base64` expression in Power Automate with the above input string yields the output `MzVGRUJFQTUyQTA3ODE2QjA5NDk1MDVFNDZFNkM4Q0IyQjlEMzg5NkE2MjUyODZCRkE0Q0IwNDIwMjQ1MjE1Nw==`.

My colleague was able to achieve the conversion through command-line with the following command: `echo "35FEBEA52A07816B0949505E46E6C8CB2B9D3896A625286BFA4CB04202452157" | xxd -r -p | base64` - however, I can't find any equivalent of this in Power Automate. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I have an answer for you but you may not like it.  The easiest way is to use a third party connector called **Advanced Data Operations** and in particular, the **C# Script Execute** operation.

https://statesolutions.com.au/c-script-execute/

https://statesolutions.com.au/pricing/

You can sign up for a free trial and give it a whirl by going to the **Pricing** page.

[image: Flow]

**Script**

```
var hexString = parameters.hexString;

byte[] byteArray = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
{
    byteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
}

var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

return base64String;
```

**Parameters**

```
{
  "hexString": @{variables('Hex String')}
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I essentially took your idea, and then used the "hack" approach of a custom connector which goes nowhere, to execute a custom C# script, and then plugged your code in as the script. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Nice idea …! Well done.